# using legacy librealsense in qtcreator and cmake

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, c++, cmake

I want to setup qt-creator for developing legacy librealsense in ubuntu16.04. I want to use CMake. I have librealsense installed on my system and the header files are in the "/usr/local/include" and the "librealsense.so" file is in the "/usr/local/lib". so I've created a simple CPP project with CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp files. my files are as follow:

main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <librealsense/rs.hpp>

int main()
{
    rs::context ctx;

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(realsense_r200)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

find_library(librealsense REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${librealsense_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${librealsense_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

there are two problems:

1. find_library(), can't find the librealsense and in the CMake cache list, in front of librealsense, I get NOT_FOUND.

to solve the first problem I added the "librealsense.so" path manually in the cache list. so I have no errors in the generation of make files. but how can I set it up to find the path automatically?

2. when I try to build my project I have undefined reference errors to some methods as below:

```
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `rs_apply_depth_control_preset(rs_device*, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x61d): undefined reference to `rs_set_device_options'
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `rs_apply_ivcam_preset(rs_device*, rs_ivcam_preset)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x734): undefined reference to `rs_reset_device_options_to_default'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d1): undefined reference to `rs_set_device_options'
main.cpp:(.text+0x869): undefined reference to `rs_set_device_options'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8ba): undefined reference to `rs_set_device_options'
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `rs::error::error(rs_error*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x2a): undefined reference to `rs_get_error_message'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x74): undefined reference to `rs_get_failed_function'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x9b): undefined reference to `rs_get_failed_function'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x102): undefined reference to `rs_get_failed_args'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x129): undefined reference to `rs_get_failed_args'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs5errorC2EP8rs_error[_ZN2rs5errorC5EP8rs_error]+0x190): undefined reference to `rs_free_error'
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `rs::context::context()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs7contextC2Ev[_ZN2rs7contextC5Ev]+0x30): undefined reference to `rs_create_context'
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `rs::context::~context()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2rs7contextD2Ev[_ZN2rs7contextD5Ev]+0x1c): undefined reference to `rs_delete_context'
CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'realsense_r200' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/all' failed
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [realsense_r200] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
18:32:02: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project realsense_r200 (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "CMake Build"
```

as you see in the CMakeLists.txt file I've linked the "librealsense.so" file to the executable, why I get these errors and how can I solve it?

thanks for your help!!!

#

### Edited Part

I changed my cmake file as below:

new CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(realsense_r200)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

find_library(REALSENSE librealsense)
find_package(Threads)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REALSENSE} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

the undefined errors have gone, but I have new errors as below:

```
/usr/local/lib/librealsense.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
/usr/local/lib/librealsense.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'realsense_r200' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/all' failed
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed

/usr/local/lib/librealsense.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [realsense_r200] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense_r200.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
23:35:55: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project realsense_r200 (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "CMake Build"
```

Comment: Correct invocation of [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_library.html) is `find_library (<VAR> name1)`. E.g. `find_library(REALSENSE librealsense)` with futher reference to the library with `${REALSENSE}`. Note also, that `REQUIRED` has no special meaning for `find_library`. It seems you confuses it with `find_package`.

Comment: hello. sorry for answering late. you are right. actually I am new to CMake and that was my wrong. I edited my CMake file as you mentioned. actually it did not find the path of ${REALSENSE} but when i manually entered it in the CMake cache the errors for undefined methods have gone. but now i have some other errors as below:

Comment: the error is:"/usr/local/lib/librealsense.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()@GLIBCXX_3.4.22"

Comment: No, do not post the error message in the comments. Instead, update your question post (and update the code in it).

Comment: so should I link the thread library to my executable target? I have searched about it and I've added `find_package(Threads)` and  link it to the executable by adding `${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}` to the target link library. actually after adding these two to CMake file i get the above error.

Comment: excuse me. I have edited my question.

Comment: When `.so` has `undefined reference to` it usually means that this library is not compatible with libraries you have, or some other incompatibility occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201771/discussion-between-amir-reza-sadeqi-and-tsyvarev).

Comment: hi Tsyvarev. I think it is solved. thanks for your help. by your comment, the undefined references for realsense library are solved and the problems for undefined references to threads were for using old version of the GCC compiler. I found it from [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221116]. now it compiles and runs without errors and also there is no need to add `find_package(Threads)` and linking it to the executable in the CMake file. thanks for your help!!!